# How do I prove that $x^2 + y^2 - 1$ irreducible is $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have the polynomial $x^2 + y^2 - 1$ in the ring $R = \mathbb{R}[x,y]$. 
I have to prove that it's irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ and I want to do it without using Eisenstein's Criterion otherwise i'd have to prove said criterion on my assignment.

Comment: Can you show that $1-y^2$ is not a square in $\Bbb R(y)$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng how does that help proving that the polynomial is irreducible? $1-y^2$ is $(1-y)(1+y)$ but I dont see how that helps

Comment: $1-y^2\equiv x^2$ in $\mathbb R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$

Comment: I still dont follow how that helps to prove that the polynomial irreducible is.

Comment: Just use the definition. Show you can't write it $x^2+y^2-1=P(x,y)Q(x,y)$ with both $P$ and $Q$ having degree $>0$.

Comment: I've tried already, $x^2+y^2-1 = fg = (a_2x+a_1y+a_0)(b_2x+b_1y+b_0) =  a_2b_2x^2 + a_1b_1y^2 + (a_2b_1 + a_1b_2)xy + (a_2b_0+a_0b_2)x + (a_1b_0 + a_0b_1)y + a_0b_0$ $a_2b_2 = a_1b_1= 1,  a_0b_0 = -1
    a_2b_1 + a_1b_2 = a_2b_0 + a_0b_2 = a_1b_0 + a_0b_1 = 0$. And then solving $a_i=\frac{\pm 1}{b_i}$. Which results in $a_0^2=a_1^2=a_2^2$ en $b_0^2=b_1^2=b_2^2$. But that's as far as I came

Comment: You can in effect (re) prove a very small explicit case of Eisenstein's criterion, without saying so or even necessarily thinking about it. Treat $\mathbb R[x,y]$ as $(\mathbb R[y])[x]$. The ring $\mathbb R[y]$ is a polynomial ring in one variable over a field, so is Euclidean... The $1-y^2=(1-y(1+y)$ is a factorization into prime elements...

Comment: Since you know that neither $a_2$ nor $b_2$ is $0$, you can use the fact that you can move a constant factor between the two polynomials to eliminate the prefactor of $x$ in the first polynomial, which effectively eliminates it in the second one as well because the product is $1$. Then you are left with 4 unknowns and much simpler equations.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x^2+y^2-1$ has a nontrivial factorization in $\mathbb R[x,y]=\mathbb R[y][x]$, say $x^2+y^2-1=(a(y)x-f(y))(b(y)x-g(y))$ for some $a,b,f,g\in\mathbb R[y]$. Comparing the coefficients we obtain
$$a(y)b(y)=1,$$
$$a(y)g(y)+b(y)f(y)=0,$$
$$f(y)g(y)=y^2-1.$$
It follows that $a=a(y)$ and $b=b(y)$ are constants, and $f(y)=-\frac abg(y)$, so
$$-\frac ab g(y)^2=y^2-1=(y+1)(y-1).$$
Note that $\mathbb R[y]$ is a UFD, so it is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f = x^2+y^2-1$ were the product of two nonconstant polynomials $P, Q$. Then clearly, $P$ and $Q$ must have both total degree $1$, since otherwise $PQ$ has total degree at least $3$.

Consider the set of points $(x, y)$ with $f(x, y) = 0$, call it $V(f)$. This is a circle. Because $f = PQ$, we have $V(f) = V(P) \cup V(Q)$. But $V(P)$ and $V(Q)$ are straight lines! Clearly, this is impossible: a circle is not the union of two straight lines. (A line and a circle intersect in at most $2$ points; not infinitely many.)

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2 + y^2 -1 = x^2 + (y^2-1) = x^2 + (y+1)(y-1) \in \mathbb{R}[y][x]$$
Defini $f\colon \mathbb{R}[y] \to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(p(y)) = p(1)$. This is a ring homomorphism with $\ker f = (y-1)$, i.e. $\mathbb{R}[y]/(y-1) \cong \mathbb{R}$. (Isomorphism theorem.) Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, $(y-1) \subset \mathbb{R}[y]$ is maximal ideal, so it is prime ideal.

Thus, by Eisenstein, $x^2 + y^2 -1 $ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[y][x]$.

Comment: Here $(y-1)^2 \not\mid y^2-1 $ since $y+1 \ne y-1$, so $\operatorname{char}\mathbb{R} \ne2$ is critical.

Comment: OP wanted to do it without Eisenstein’s criterion

Comment: omg I misread the OP's article. @J.W.Tanner

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Angina Seng's comment: We have $\mathbb{R}[x,y]=\mathbb{R}[y][x]$. Considering $\deg_x$, we see that a non trivial factor of $f$ must have degree $1$ in $x$. In particular, if $f$ is not irreducible, it has a root in $\mathbb{R}(y)$, meaning that $1-y^2$ is a square in the field $\mathbb{R}(y)$.

This is false: since $y-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[y]$, one may consider the $y-1$-adic valuation. If  $1-y^2$ is a square, its $1-y$-adic valuation must be even. But it is equal to one (since $y-1$ and $y+1$ are not associate), hence a contradiction.